# Learn Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have coded a little bit In objective-c before swift came out. I can't say that I know objective-c very well, but I have familiarized myself with it.

Should I continue my familiarization with objective-c, or should I spend my energy on learning swift?

Something tells me that I should keep going with objective-c, because It has been around for several of years, and that the majority of the apps are written In objective-c.

Comment: If you are not forced by your employee to work with Objective-C then there is no reasons not to use Swift. There is more and more tutorials for Swift showing up and if you know basics about Obj-c it shouldn't be that hard for you to re-write obj-c functions in Swift. Also, Swift is not that hard to learn either so it's not like you have to spend too much time learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your motives.

If you want to get a job at a company which has an existing app written in Obj-C then it might be wise to learn it. However if you say you know Swift, it increases your chances of getting hired, because it proves you are learning the new/hot technology.

If you want to create your own apps, you should definitely learn Swift. But you should learn Obj-C syntax in beginners level, just understand what a function, variable, parameter and these stuff are, so you can have an easier time working with Obj-C libraries. You don't need to be able to write Obj-C, just reading and understanding is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same dilemma and after a small research I proceeded with objective-c for now. the reason is that I have to be able to work on the apps that are already written in objective-c and apple will not shut it down at least few more years.

on the other hand, swift is easier to learn especially if you have obj-c background, so it can be adopted during the time, slowly and paralelly with using obj-c.

that's my opinion, there is no right answer to your question.